# Cloud Run, how to access root folder to upload

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I succeeded in uploading the node js container image to cloud run through docker and it works fine.

But now I have to upload some executable file in the root directory in binary form. (Probably, it would be nice to set basic file permissions as well) But I can't find a way to access it.. I know it's running on Debian 64-bit, right? How can I access the root folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it is technically possible to download/copy a file to a running Cloud Run instance, that action would need to take place on every cold start. Depending on how large the files are, you could run out of memory as file system changes are in-memory. Containers should be considered read-only file systems for most use cases except for temporary file storage during computation.

Cloud Run does not provide an interface to log in to an instance or remotely access files. The Docker exec type commands are not supported. That level of functionality would need to be provided by your application.

Instead, rebuild your container with updates/changes and redeploy.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks, The size of this file module is very small and it is provided by a third party (.exe file for file conversion). The reason I'm trying to do this is that the guide I received says I have to upload the file in "binary mode" and set the file permission to 755. I deployed to Cloud Run using Cloud Code in IntelliJ, and when I tested it on localhost, it worked perfectly (with the Windows file they gave me). And of course I replaced it with the Linux file when deploying to Cloud Run. However,error occurs, I guess that the file was converted while going to Cloud Run. How do I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps what I need the most right now is to upload the file in binary mode. Any possible way?

Comment: @abarw - Add that feature to your application. Cloud Run does not provide that ability.